# How to convert SATA power port to Slimline power port

Tags: sata

I want to convert 15 pin SATA to 6 pin Slimline but there is problem the 15 pin SATA contain 3 "+5V" and 6 ground but the slimline one only contain 2 "+5V" pines and 2 ground with 2 additional pines DP and M

Can someone please help me with the wiring.

[image: this is a 15 pin sata power i want to convert it]

[image: i want the result a 6 pin sata power]

Comment: Voting to close because this is an off-topic *usage* question, but even more so because it has been abandoned and the anti-community daemon keeps uselessly dredging it up

Comment: This is an off topic usage question and long abandoned

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 *5V* wires and connect them to slimline (i.e. Pin :- 9, 10). Leave the third *5V* wire.

Use 2 *GND* wires and connect them to slimline (i.e. Pin :- 12, 13). Leave the other four *GND* wires.

The SATA to Slimline converters available in the market only seem to use one wire for *5V* & one wire for *GND*. They bridge the two *5V* & *GND* at the Slimline side.

Using one wire for each is fine but I would recommend you to go with the 2-wire approach.

Comment: thank you  you are a life saver  what about "device presence" and "manufacturer diagnostic " pin 8 and 11 in pic 2 what should i do with them

Comment: No need to attach them to anything.